document is not defined in Next JS Zego cloud
I have been implementing zego cloud to my next js application, it throws error which shows document is not defined
I am using the "use client" in my next js application to access react hooks and DOM of the browser but it throws document is not defined

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

i use Nextjs like you and i has the problems like you
you must to do like this, import zegocloud in function


// example this is function
const invite = async () => {
            const { ZegoUIKitPrebuilt } = await import(
                '@zegocloud/zego-uikit-prebuilt'
            )
            
            const TOKEN = ZegoUIKitPrebuilt.generateKitTokenForTest(
                appID,
                serverSecret,
                roomID,
                userID,
                userName,
            )
          // your logic code
     }



or another answers
How to fix 'ReferenceError: document is not defined' when using ZEGOCLOUD API with Next.js?

sorry for my english haha
